# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with shared package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, lerna

I am currently working on building a `shared` node package between my NextJS app & Firebase Functions backend. Here is the current directory structure:

```
├── backend/
│   └── functions/
├── product/
└── shared/
```

Here is my `index.ts` that I export from my `shared` package:

```
import { SUPPORTED_WEBSITES } from "./websites/supportedWebsites";
import { getSupportedWebsite, addAffilateLink } from "./websites/utils";

export default { SUPPORTED_WEBSITES, getSupportedWebsite, addAffilateLink };
```

I then reference in `firebase/functions`:

```
import shared from "shared"

export const exampleFunc = functions.https.onCall(
   async (data, context) => {
      shared.getSupportedWebsite("amazon.com")
   }
)
```

I then run `firebase emulators:start` to try to test out `exampleFunc` and I get:

```
import { SUPPORTED_WEBSITES } from "./websites/supportedWebsites";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I am currently symlinking `shared` to `backend/functions` via [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/).

Please let me know if you have any ideas/need more clarification.

Comment: Add `"type": "module"` to the `package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I was able to fix this by compiling my `shared/src` files into commonjs files via `tsc`